# Docker-Compose command not found on Raspberry Pi 3 Ubuntu Server 21.10

Tags: docker-compose, raspberry-pi, ubuntu-server

I keep having 'command not found' after installing Docker-Compose:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ docker-compose
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose: line 1: Not: command not found
```

My Setup:

- Raspberry Pi 3
- Ubuntu Server 21.10

Here is what I did to install Docker-Compose:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev libssl-dev
sudo apt install python3-dev
sudo apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
sudo pip3 install docker-compose
```

Comment: The error message doesn't say that `docker-compose` wasn't found. It says that the command `Not`, which is mentioned in the first line of that file, was not found.